# Prove the derivative of $\arctan(x)$ using derivative definition

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives, inverse

> Prove that the derivative of $\arctan(x)$ is $\frac1{1+x^2}$ using definition of derivative

I'm not allowed to use derivative of inverse function, infinite series or l'Hopital.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some trigonometry. Since $\arctan (x+h)-\arctan x=\arctan\tfrac{h}{1+x(x+h)}$, $\lim_{h\to 0}\tfrac{\arctan (x+h)-\arctan x}{h}=\tfrac{1}{\lim_{h\to 0} (1+x(x+h))}$ (because $\arctan\theta\approx\theta$ for small $\theta$).

Comment: $arctanθ≈θ$ is proven using derivative ($f'(0)=1$). So, I don't think It can be used.
Also I can't understand from where does that rule come from $\arctan (x+h)-\arctan x=\arctan\tfrac{h}{1+x(x+h)}$

Comment: Firstly, no calculus is needed in that approximation; you just need a famous diagram-based proof that acute $\theta$ satisfy $0\le\cos\theta\le\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}\le1\le\frac{\tan\theta}{\theta}\le\sec\theta$, followed by the squeeze theorem. Secondly, it comes from the tangent's double angle formula.

Comment: *Compound angle formula.